# Suppress scientific notation in geopandas plot legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, format, legend, geopandas

I am new to geopandas and am trying to plot a map with a legend in regular notation not scientific notation. I understand I must use the legend_kwds and know about the 'fmt' keyword but I've tried multiple settings to no avail. Here is my current code drawing up the map:

```
img = geodf.plot(figsize=(16, 16), column='rate', cmap='Reds', legend=True,
                       legend_kwds={'label': "Rate",
                                    'orientation': "horizontal",
                                   'pad': 0.01,
                                   'fmt': '%f'})
```

[image]

How do I suppress scientific notation of the legend?

EDIT:
I have tried

```
img.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
```

This does not solve my issue. The legend is still showing values in 1e6.
This is because `img` refers to the main `axes` of the plot, not the `legend`'s axes. So that, the mentioned answer is definitely not working for this question.

**SOLUTION**:
@swatchai has provided the solution I was looking for. The `legend_kwds` to use is `'format':"%.0f"`, not `'fmt'`.

Comment: In `legend_kwds`, you should use `'format':"%.0f"`, (`fmt` is not recognized).

Comment: Someone claims that this question already has an answer. Such answer works on the main axes of the plot, not the legend's axes in this question.

Comment: @swatchai SOLVED! Thank you so much, this was the answer I needed!

Comment: If it is solved, you should answer your own question, and mark it as accepted answer. Make a bold/clear comment that this is not the other already answered somewhere else.I will vote up your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot mark my question as solved because someone claimed it already had an answer. I will make an edit in the original question in bold

Comment: img.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')  WORKED!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to format x-axis :

```
img.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
img.show()
```

Comment: That didn't work, the legend is still showing in scientific notation

Comment: I think the legend attributes are different from the x-axis of plot, which is why I was hoping there would be a solution using legend_kwds

Comment: img.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')  WORKED!